# Keep textbox value when changing record

Tags: ms-access, vba, ms-access-2010

I have one form where I can view bought items from customer, but when I want to put new record in that form owner_id (on my language ID_vlasnika) is set to null and I want to automatically put owner_id on same value as in record before.

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is "a more elegant fix" - set the *DefaultValue* of the field in the OnCurrent event:

```
Private Sub Form_Current

    If Not Me.NewRecord = True Then
        Me!ID_vlasnika.DefaultValue = Me!ID_vlasnika.Value
    End If

End Sub
```

Comment: I am not sure what exactly were you thinking. Where should I put this code?

Comment: @IvanNavratil it goes in the Form's `Current()` event, as stated in the header.

Comment: Just for optimization, you can write "If Not Me.NewRecord Then", you haven't to test if a boolean is equal to True or False, you can simply test "If boolean then". You can do it whatever the programmation language you are actually using.

Answer (score 1):

Someone else may have a more elegant fix, but here's something that will work:

As this looks like a bound form, any time you click the new record navigation button it will clear all fields. As far as I know, there aren't ways to change this behavior.

However, You can hide the navigation buttons from the form's property pane and instead use a command button to "Create New Record". Then have a macro or VBA run some actions to capture the current record values, create a new record, and then copy the values back to your controls.

Here is an example of the VBA code:

```
Dim a As String
'Declare as many dimensions as fields you want to copy

a = Me![Naziv uredaja]
'Set variables for all of your other fields

'Next line creates a new record on your form
DoCmd.GoToRecord , , acNewRec

'Set your field back to the previous value
Me![Naziv uredaja] = a
'Repeat for each field you want to copy.

End Sub
```

Comment: I am getting error on this line of code. "DoCmd.GoToRecord , , acNewRec."

Comment: @IvanNavratil delete the period at the end. Sorry that's my fault.